# Mostar / Esconder Button e TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo meu primeiro App no Android Studio, mas estou com dificuldade para fazer algo relativamente fácil.
Preciso que ao Clicar em um Botão, seja mostrado o TextView e outro Botão(O qual ira esconder o TextView ao ser clicado novamente). Mas todas as alternativas que pesquisei e tentei estão travando o App.
Alguém teria algum código semelhante ou teria alguma sugestão?

---

Após ajuda do @Skywalker o código ficou como se segue, já esta funcionando.

**XML**

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mostar_1"
    android:id="@+id/btnMostar_1"
    android:onClick= "clickBtnMostar_1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mostar_2"
    android:id="@+id/btnMostar_2"
    android:onClick= "clickBtnMostar_2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LyMostar_1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible">


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Texto 1"
    android:id="@+id/textMostar_1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LyMostar_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Esconder1"
    android:id="@+id/btnEsconder1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnMostar_1"
        android:onClick= "clickBtnEsconder1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LyMostar_2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Texto 2"
        android:id="@+id/textMostar_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LyMostar_2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Esconder2"
        android:id="@+id/btnEsconder2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnMostar_2"
        android:onClick= "clickBtnEsconder2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public LinearLayout LyMostar_1;
public LinearLayout LyMostar_2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela2);
    LyMostar_1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LyMostar_1);
}

public void clickBtnMostar_1(View view) {

    LyMostar_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void clickBtnEsconder1 (View esc){
    LyMostar_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}


public void clickBtnMostar_2(View view) {
    LyMostar_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void clickBtnEsconder2 (View esc){
    LyMostar_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

}

Comment: O que você já tentou? Mesmo sem sucesso, adicione o código do que já fez na pergunta, clicando em [edit].

Comment: Obrigado pela dica...Já editei o post e coloquei o código que estou tentando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coloque tudo que você deseja esconder dentro de um LinearLayout ou algum Layout de sua preferencia e coloque um id para esse Layout no xml.

```
<LinearLayout
        ....Layout principal da activity>
       <Button
            ...button que faz a ação de esconder o conteudo desejado
           />

       <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/ll_conteudo"
              ... layout que sera escondido...>
           <TextView .... />
           <Button ..... />
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

No código java no onCreate da sua Activity, vc faz o `casting` desse layout

```
llConteudo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_conteudo);
```

No listener do botão de ação que deve esconder/mostrar o conteudo você implementa da seguinte forma.

```
if(show){
    llConteudo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    show = false;
}else{
    llConteudo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    show = true;
}
```

Repare que você precisa criar uma flag(um boolean) para saber o estado em que está o conteúdo, invisivel ou visivel. 

Eu não sei seu nivel de conhecimento, mas caso estiver com dúvidas posso ser menos objetivo e exemplificar mais.

Seu XML deve ficar mais ou menos dessa forma:

Comment: Obrigado @Skywalker pela dica.  Sobre o meu nível de conhecimento presumo ser pouco, mas acho que a unica parte que fiquei com duvida seria sobre "fazer casting de layout"... Poderia explicar como faço?

Editei o Post e coloquei o meu Código após a alteração com a sua sugestão.

Comment: Nesse caso fazer o casting é vc pegar a referencia do layout que vc declarou no xml para trabalhar no código java. Casting envolve herença e polimorfismo, da uma boa pesquisada sobre polimorfismo que vc vai entende.

Comment: adicionei uma correção no codigo, view.findViewById, remova o view. O métodos findViewById é da propria activity, mesma coisa que this.findViewById. Eu havia usado o view. pois confundi que vc estava trabalhando com fragments.

Comment: Da uma olhada no xml eu modifiquei, acho q vc n entendeu ainda.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado Obrigado @Skywalker, no geral já consegui fazer o código funcionar como queria. O único porem,  e que minha tela não se "auto-organiza", por exemplo, gostaria que o Layout1 surgi-se entre o Botão1 e Botão2, e após o Layout se ocultado, os botões voltassem a ficar um em baixo do outro. Creio que seja algo fácil, só me falta conhecimento. Preciso abrir uma nova pergunta pra isso?
Outra duvida seria, eu preciso apagar a pergunta depois de resolvida?

Comment: Troque onde tem View.INVISIBLE por View.GONE, ai não vai ocupa o espaço. Não precisa excluir a pergunta, ela pode ajudar outros.